# R - Web Scraping with https login form

Tags: r, authentication, web-scraping

I am trying to post a login form through `R` so that I can run some web scraping (which is not available unless I login). I thought I had everything working but whenever I try to access a page beyond the login, it keeps returning back to the login page (i.e. the post form didn't work or it hasn't recognised that I have already logged in). Could this be down to cookies?

This is what I have so far using `rcurl`:

```
loginurl = "https://shop.supervalu.ie/shopping/StartShopping/login.aspx"
dataurl = "https://shop.supervalu.ie/shopping/shopping/shop.aspx?catid=150300005&PDEPTID=8"

pars=list(
   `ctl00$ctl00$cphContent$cphMain$ucntrlLogin$txtEmailAddress` = "email",
   `ctl00$ctl00$cphContent$cphMain$ucntrlLogin$txtPassword` = "password",
   `ctl00$ctl00$cphContent$cphMain$ucntrlLogin$btnLogin` = "LOGIN"
) 

agent="Mozilla/5.0"

curl = getCurlHandle()
curlSetOpt(cookiejar="cookies.txt",  useragent = agent, followlocation = TRUE, curl=curl)

html=postForm(loginurl, .params = pars, curl = curl)

html=getURL(dataurl, curl=curl)
```